# Cannot install a library in lambda layer and use it in lambda layer custom script

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda-layers, ncurses-cdk

I am deploying a lambda function using CDK python.

This is my stack for the lambdas:

```py
import os
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_stepfunctions as _aws_stepfunctions,
    aws_stepfunctions_tasks as _aws_stepfunctions_tasks,
    aws_lambda,
    App, Duration, Stack,
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    aws_sns as sns,
    aws_sns_subscriptions as sns_subs,
    aws_iam as iam,
)


class LambdaStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, app: App,
                 id: str,
                 upload_image_bucket,
                 **kwargs) -> None:
                     
        super().__init__(app, id, **kwargs)
        
        
        schema_response_layer = aws_lambda.LayerVersion(self, 'lambda-layer',
                  code = aws_lambda.AssetCode('lambdas/lambda_layers/schema_response_layer/'),
                  compatible_runtimes = [aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
                  layer_version_name="schema_response_layer"
        )
        
        
        policy_textract = iam.PolicyStatement( # Restrict to listing and describing tables
                        actions=[   "textract:AnalyzeDocument",
                                    "textract:DetectDocumentText",
                                    "textract:GetDocumentAnalysis",
                                    "textract:GetDocumentTextDetection",
                                    "textract:AnalyzeExpense"],
                        resources=["*"]
        )

        store_image = aws_lambda.Function(
            self, 'store_imagey',
            function_name="storage_image_test_1",
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset('lambdas/lambda_functions/store_image'),
            handler='store_image.store_image_handler',
            environment={
                            'BUCKET_NAME': upload_image_bucket.bucket_name,
                         },
            initial_policy=[policy_textract],
            layers=[schema_response_layer]
        )
        
        upload_image_bucket.grant_read_write(store_image)
        
        self.store_image_ld = store_image
```

as you can see, I am creating a lambda layer, that I want to use in my store_image function.

I can import this lambda layer without problems using this import:

```py
from response_schema import Response
```

This is my layer python code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator

class Headers(BaseModel):
    content_type: str = "application/json"
    access_control: str =  "*"
    allow = "GET, OPTIONS, POST"
    access_control_allow_methods: str  = "*"
    access_control_allow_headers: str  = "*"
    
    
class Response(BaseModel):
    status_code: str = "200"
    body: str
    headers: Headers = Headers()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'store_image': No module named 'pydantic'
```

I don't know how to install the pydantic library in my lambda layer and use this library in the lambda layer code.

The lambda layer structure folder is:

[image]

In the `requirements.txt` file I have:

```
pydantic==1.10.4
```

But it seems that is not installing the pydantic library in my lambda layer. I have tried to install the library in the lambda layer folder using:

```
pip install -t . pydantic==1.10.4
```

But is not working neither.

How can I install a library in my lambda layer and use it in my lambda layer custom script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Python packages from the requirements.txt file, you can use [aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha.PythonFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha/PythonFunction.html) construct. In this case you need to replace your LayerVersion construct with [PythonLayerVersion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha/PythonLayerVersion.html) construct.

If you want to use Function and LayerVersion constructs, you need to download libraries to your project. You can use this [article](https://medium.com/geekculture/deploying-aws-lambda-layers-with-python-8b15e24bdad2) as a reference.